# Jmeter 4.0 unable to access menus

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have downloaded a fresh copy of JMeter 4.0 a couple of times and everytime it opens it throws a Java.lang.exceptionInInitializerError. When I look at the log it mentions the following. I have not installed any third party libraries. Any ideas on how I resolve this would be appreciated. Thanks

Error initializing menus, check configuration if using 3rd party libraries
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$IndentIcon.getIconWidth(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabelImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at

Comment: you have some plugin installed which is either incompatible, or buggy.

Comment: can you show full stacktrace ? thanks

Comment: Full stack trace

Comment: where is it ? I don’t see it. Thanks

Comment: 2018-05-11 17:49:30,091 ERROR o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Error initializing menus, check configuration if using 3rd party libraries
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath(Win32ShellFolder2.java:571) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
 at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$400(Win32ShellFolder2.java:72) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
 .......
2018-05-11 17:49:30,094 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
 at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:92) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]

Comment: the same thing happened. decided to remove the module dracula.jar - and ok. may be this is bug 62110 https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@jmeter.apache.org/msg12336.html

Comment: @user3803807, did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: can anyone solve this problem? I have no dracular.jar

Comment: It's actually darcula.jar - it's the dark skin

Answer (score 3):

I have removed Dracula.jar from lib, then no such issue reoccured.

Comment: Same thing fixed it for me.  I had assumed it was my locked down work laptop messing with me.