# With Jmeter 5.1.1 r1855137, not able to save any script. Getting exceptions in log

Tags: jmeter

Environment Details: - 
Jmeter Version: 
5.1.1 r1855137

Jave Version: - 
C:\Users\username>java -version
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b10, mixed mode)

OS:
Windows 10 Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.557)

Problem Statement: - 
After creating a test plan, while trying to save it, it's not saving and getting different exceptions.

Below is command prompt output.

```
================================================================================
Don't use GUI mode for load testing !, only for Test creation and Test debugging.
For load testing, use CLI Mode (was NON GUI):
   jmeter -n -t [jmx file] -l [results file] -e -o [Path to web report folder]
& increase Java Heap to meet your test requirements:
   Modify current env variable HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" in the jmeter batch file
Check : https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
================================================================================
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger. See log file for details.
```

Below is Jmeter log.

```
2019-07-08 09:45:13,969 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2019-07-08 09:45:13,984 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2019-07-08 09:45:13,985 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2019-07-08 09:45:13,990 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2019 The Apache Software Foundation
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.1.1 r1855137
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_212
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Windows 10
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=10.0
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=null
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
2019-07-08 09:45:13,991 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =8
2019-07-08 09:45:13,995 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
2019-07-08 09:45:13,995 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
2019-07-08 09:45:13,995 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1
2019-07-08 09:45:13,995 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin
2019-07-08 09:45:13,996 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin
2019-07-08 09:45:13,998 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 192.168.0.100 Name: USER-HOST FullName: USER-HOST.domain.com
2019-07-08 09:45:14,193 INFO o.a.j.g.a.LookAndFeelCommand: Installing Darcula LAF
2019-07-08 09:45:14,208 INFO o.a.j.g.a.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: com.bulenkov.darcula.DarculaLaf [Darcula]
2019-07-08 09:45:14,208 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting LAF to: com.bulenkov.darcula.DarculaLaf
2019-07-08 09:45:14,265 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties
2019-07-08 09:45:15,770 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-07-08 09:45:15,771 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-07-08 09:45:15,771 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-07-08 09:45:15,771 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-07-08 09:45:15,771 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2019-07-08 09:45:15,771 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2019-07-08 09:45:15,917 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: Exception checking for keytool existence, will return false, try another way.
2019-07-08 09:45:16,320 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_212\bin\keytool'
2019-07-08 09:45:16,320 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\proxyserver.jks
2019-07-08 09:45:16,477 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='D:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin'
2019-07-08 09:45:16,888 WARN o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Could not instantiate class: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui.SmtpSamplerGui
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.getGUIComponent(MenuFactory.java:174) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.initializeMenus(MenuFactory.java:141) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.<clinit>(MenuFactory.java:106) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:92) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:185) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:46) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$IndentIcon.getIconWidth(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabelImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.layoutCL(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.valueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JList.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.setListSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.access$300(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.itemStateChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.access$800(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.access$1100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$5.propertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui.SmtpPanel.initComponents(SmtpPanel.java:576) ~[ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui.SmtpPanel.<init>(SmtpPanel.java:117) ~[ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui.SmtpSamplerGui.makeDataPanel(SmtpSamplerGui.java:190) ~[ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui.SmtpSamplerGui.init(SmtpSamplerGui.java:170) ~[ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.gui.SmtpSamplerGui.<init>(SmtpSamplerGui.java:47) ~[ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    ... 26 more
2019-07-08 09:45:17,093 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2019-07-08 09:45:17,093 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2019-07-08 09:45:17,094 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2019-07-08 09:45:17,094 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2019-07-08 09:45:22,906 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.computeFileName(Save.java:203) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.doAction(Save.java:165) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$IndentIcon.getIconWidth(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabelImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.layoutCL(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.valueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JList.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.setListSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.access$300(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.itemStateChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.access$800(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.access$1100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$5.propertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger.<clinit>(FileDialoger.java:40) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    ... 18 more
2019-07-08 09:45:53,594 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.computeFileName(Save.java:203) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.doAction(Save.java:165) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.doActionNow(ActionRouter.java:125) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractAction.popupShouldSave(AbstractAction.java:77) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.doAction(Start.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

Comment: Below are exceptions in command prompt: - 

Uncaught Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger. See log file for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this module:
apache-jmeter-5.1.1\lib\darcula.jar

I'm not sure about the consequences of removing this, but that fixed my problem. Look at the following link.

[Jmeter 4.0 unable to access menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097525/jmeter-4-0-unable-to-access-menus)

Comment: Thank You for sharing your experience. YES, IT IS WORKING! But, removing the darcula.jar makes it the old style Jmeter. I just hope that all the functionalities remain intact :).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be, that the directory – you saved to earlier – has been removed in the meantime? If that is the case, you could have hit https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63945.

Answer (score 0):

If it is nightly build then download stable [release 5.1.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and try again. There are chances some lib is missing or having conflicts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The build I'm using is a stable one and is the same build as the link shared by you. 
I'm still facing the same issue even after again downloading the build from the location shared by you.